# Intellisense turned off on new documents

Tags: html, colors, intellisense, doc

I'm wondering why my intellisense is not working on new documents only. I've checked all my settings. Uninstalled and re-installed VS studio. Unfortunately this it still it is not displaying color or suggestions.

Comment: `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General. Make sure “Auto List Members” is checked. Also, make sure “Parameter Information” is checked.`

Comment: `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General. go to “Basic” and then “IntelliSense.” Make sure you have the following three checked:
1. Show completion list after a character is typed
2. Highlight matching portions of completion list items
3. Show completion item filters`

Comment: Or just read this detailed post on it [Visual Studio IntelliSense Not Working? What To Do.](https://blog.submain.com/visual-studio-intellisense-not-working/)

Comment: It is not just VS code ... nothing is working. Sublime or Atom. all new documents do not have color or "intellisense" ...